# GeoCoder returns different long/lat identifier for geometry-location value

Tags: objective-c, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder

it seems that the GeoResult of the Google Geocoder retuns a different identifier tag for the geometry-location value since yesterday. In the past they used for the long/lat values the Va/Ua identifiers in their JSON like result object. The longitude identifier changed yesterday from Va to Ta. Is this common to any Google request results, that identifier will change over time? If this is the case, how does Google inform developers about such an API change?

In my code (Objective-C), I will parse for these identifiers with help of a JSON parser to receive the current long/lat values. Therefore I have to stick to the current used notation of such an identifier because a JSON object will be converted to an array or a dictionary and the later navigation through the dictionaries will be done through an e.g. [locationResult objectForKey:@"Va"] call.

Any other experience out there with Google JavaScript APIs.
Otherwise I have to check for the long/lat result in JavaScript and then return the final results back to my Objective-C code. But I still would prefere the way to return the whole JSON result object to my Objective-C code and parse it there.

Regards

---

I will update my own question with my latest investigations:
Google will change the internal format of the JSON object quite frequently, today they changed it again. Therefore I have to evaluate the whole Geocoder result on JavaScript side and not in Objectiv-C by parsing the result with help of an JSON parser. Sad for me but I assume its more safe to stick to the JavaScript API instead of the raw result. :-(

Thanks for the answers!!!

Comment: This sounds for me as if you are requesting the results delivered for the JS-API not using the JS-API. This is not legal.

Comment: Here we are again. ;-) Now we are talking about the JS-API. Good to know that this is not legal, I just tried to find some additional informations about this on the google api doc sites without success. Could you please provide a link? Nevertheless I will change my code to stick from now for the whole geocoding process to the JS-API. But it was still quite interesting to see, that the internal JSON like geocoding result will change from time to time with some object identifiers. Regards.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/terms 10.1.1. (a-c)

Answer (score 8):

Try calling the lat() and lng() functions to get the values stored in the geometry.location object.

instead of

```
var lat = results[0].geometry.location.Ua;
var long = results[0].geometry.location.Va;
```

Use

```
var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
var long = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
```

This is what I am using for a javascript project that got hit by the same problem tody.

Comment: Worked for me. I was hit by same problem.

Comment: You are right, but in my case I was returning the whole result to my Objective-C code back and had no longer access to the JavaScript API. So I have to change my code on both sides now. Still, its better to change the code now and stick to the JavaScript API as a failing software out in the market. ;-)

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me too.  How did you know about the lat() lng() methods?  I didn't find any mention on the geocoder or the geometry library pages.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are talking about, but the JSON-response did only return the elements defined here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?hl=de#JSON

There is no Va,Ua,Ta or similar.

The elements are lat and lng, nothing else.

Comment: Sorry for the late response.... In my case I was sending the whole result object of the Google geocoder to my Objective-C code and parsing it then there. Inside of that JSON-object they specify the geometry like this: geometry = { location = { Xa = "52.49833";
 Ya = "13.295769999999948"; };

Comment: Can you please say to what URL you are sending the request?

Comment: There is no real URL in my case. If I unterstood you right, you are talking about the Maps API WebServices, arent you? I am not using the static GeoCoding API based on an URL request, instead of this I am using the JavaScript Geocoding API.